# How do I make these circles with radius in sketch?

Tags: interface-design, sketch-app

[image]

[image]

I am trying to make the following effects in sketch. As presented in the picture, they seem to have a curved and border radius cut to their ends.

Answer (score 1):

To create arc we need Scissors tool.

First, create oval with no fill and desired border color.
[image]

Select Edit tool and place point on oval where you want to be arc's end
[image]

Then select Scissors tool
[image]

Hover over the oval and cut unnecessary parts of oval
[image]

At the end select desired ends of the resulting arc by clicking gear icon on Borders tool.
[image]

In that way you can create any arcs, combine them and get desired result.

[image]

You can download sketch file **[here](http://ge.tt/2SIPjSf2)**

Answer (score -2):

Sketch is a bit primitive, all jokes and puns aside.

The easiest way, make an arc, give it the width you want, then place a small circle at each end, in the same size as your width. Cheating, but... well, pretty much everything is a cheat, in graphics.